# jenkins lock step must be called with a body

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to acquire a lock for a stage that runs within another stages.
But facing below error,
java.lang.IllegalStateException: lock step must be called with a body

earlier tried with options, but cannot pass label value as dynamic value, hence had to move to stage.

below is the pipeline -

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'tierra-devops-sjc-01' }
    environment {
        td3_device_label = ''
    }
    stages {
        stage('determine testbed') {
            steps {
                script {
                    load "/home/jenkins/DUT1.env"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Start QA') {
            when {
                //beforeOptions true
                not { environment name: 'skip_qa', value: '1' }
            }
            stages {
                stage ('lock testbed') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            lock(label: "${DUT_LABEL}", quantity: 1, variable: 'testbed', resource: null)
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage ('step1') {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo step1"
                    }
                }
                stage ('step2') {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo step2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I should lock for start QA stage and release when all stage/stages inside it are completed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate `unlock` step. You call the `lock` step with a body, exactly like the error message tells you.

```
lock(label: "${DUT_LABEL}", ...) {
    // All the protected code
}
```